# Trim all newlines from String in Kotlin - idiomatic way

Tags: string, kotlin, newline

Is there a built-in/standard lib method to trim all new lines from a string, not only from the beginning or the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no special stdlib function to my knowledge that specifically removes new lines, but you could simply use `text.replace("\n", "")` if you're only interested in removing `\n` characters.

If you want to cover more cases, like more line ending characters/sequences, or whitespace after new lines, you can also use a regex. For instance `text.replace(Regex("""(\r\n)|\n"""), "")`, but that may be overkill in many cases.

Yet another option is to get the lines themselves independently, and then join them back together with an empty separator:

```kotlin
text.lines().joinToString("")
```

Comment: I wonder if `text.replace(System.lineSeparator(), "")` would be an alternative…

Comment: It really depends on the use case to be frank, and in particular it depends on where the string comes from. If it's read from a file in the local file system, then yes, maybe `lineSeparator()` is worth considering. But then you might want to read the file directly as a sequence of lines instead of a big text if what you want is to get rid of line separators anyway. And in most other cases, it is probably not what you want (e.g. text received on the network), basically any case where the line separator will not depend on that of the local system.

Comment: OK, thanks for those points… I like `joinToString("")` better anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need to remove all empty lines (without any symbols, like: `\n\n`) you could use this extension:

```
fun String.trimEmptyLines() = trim().replace("\n+".toRegex(), replacement = "\n")
```

Example input:

```
1
2

3


4
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```